# Export video in Gallery not showing properly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gallery

Using Android 9 (Samsung S8), I need to export a video from the app internal directory to the gallery. When I use my export method, the video is not showing in the gallery, until another app refresh the Gallery by recording a video from my camera app for example (but restart Gallery only does not work). I do call MediaScannerConnection.scanFile though...

Moreover, the video title&display name set in the ContentValues is not the right one when looking at the video detail information (once visible in the gallery).

```
fun exportInGallery(videoFileName: String, videoPathToCopy: String,context: Context, onCompletion: (String) -> Unit){


    val valuesVideo = ContentValues()
            valuesVideo.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, videoFileName)
    valuesVideo.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, videoFileName)
    valuesVideo.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
    valuesVideo.put(
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED,
        System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000
    )

    val savedUri = context.contentResolver.insert(
        MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        valuesVideo
    )!!

    val pfd: ParcelFileDescriptor
    try {
        pfd = context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(savedUri, "w")!!
        val out = FileOutputStream(pfd.fileDescriptor)

        val videoFileToCopy = File(videoPathToCopy)
        val `in` = FileInputStream(videoFileToCopy)
        val buf = ByteArray(8192)
        var len: Int
        while (`in`.read(buf).also { len = it } > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len)
        }
        out.close()
        `in`.close()
        pfd.close()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }


    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, arrayOf(savedUri.toString()), arrayOf("video/mp4")
    ) { path, uri ->
        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned $path:")
        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=$uri")
        onCompletion(savedUri.toString())

    }

}
```

Comment: You got an uri from the media store to save your file to. It does not make sense to call the mediascanner afterwards or at all.

Comment: Android version of used device? Your code is not Android 11+ ready.

Comment: `from the app internal directory` You better mention full path as there is a lot of confusion in such namings.

Comment: `(once visible in the gallery).` There is no gallery. Only apps with names like Gallery, Photos, Fotos and such. They all get their info from the media store. Which app did you use?

Comment: As mentioned, I use a Samsung S8 with Android 9. I use the Gallery app from OneUI. BTW, in the phone files, I can see the video but with wrong metadata until the video get visible in the Gallery.
I use the MediaScanner because it didn't work without it neither, so I supposed it was required. Here is the videoPathToCopy /data/user/0/com.feelback.clipfeelback/cache/tempClipVideos/clipVideo_1634720756422.mp4